# Why can't I access APIs deployed in a newly created Jetty base directory?

Tags: java, jetty

I am using Jetty server for my apps. I have a web app, and when I deploy it in `${JETTY_HOME}/webapps`, it works fine: I can access the APIs I have created locally and remotely.

But when I create a new Jetty base directory, and deploy my web app there, I cannot access these APIs and I get a 404 error.

Any idea about things I might have done incorrectly? I am new in web development, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Update:
 So these are the steps I did when I created the new Jetty base directory:

```
mkdir /opt/web
cd /opt/web
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy
```

then I placed my WAR file in `/opt/web/webapps`. From the new jetty base directory, I started the server with

```
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar jetty.port=8000
```

This is the log when the server started.

```
WARNING: Property jetty.port in <command-line> already set in /opt/web/start.ini
2015-05-14 12:11:49.973:INFO::main: Logging initialized @659ms
2015-05-14 12:11:50.278:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.10.v20150310
2015-05-14 12:11:50.310:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/web/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-05-14 12:11:51.271:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /myapi, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2015-05-14 12:11:51.305:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@47cdc2ce{/myapi,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8000-myapi.war-myapi-any-1456158384990153592.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/myapi.war}
2015-05-14 12:11:51.328:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5171c41f{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8000}
2015-05-14 12:11:51.329:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @2015ms
```

Comment: Probably need to point Jetty to your new basedir or so. Post some config and accesslog excerpts. Not much to go by here as it is...

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup he's doing it right.  What API's are you wanting to use?  What's the error message like?  Have any stacktraces?  Just having http and deploy modules is common, but it seems you want more.  What else do you need?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt basically these APIs should just read some files in the system. There are no error messages shown in the server's log, just the 404 when I tried to access these APIs from a browser. And that's what confuses me since these APIs work when deployed in Jetty home directory, but not in the new Jetty base.

Comment: @NickOcampo I'm sorry, but your description isn't making any sense to me.  Can you edit your question to include the code of how you are attempting to access these files?